# Can't get the images to display (Flutter image picker and image cropper)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

trying to get a list of images to display in my app, With each image having a delete button for users to remove unwanted photos before uploading to firebase. Haven't gotten to the firebase upload yet, but can't seem to make it work. Somethings wrong somewhere. Hoping someone could spot the problem. I'm new to flutter and dart coding so I'm a bit confused.

````
  File? _imageFile;
  List<File> _imageFiles = [];

  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final croppedFile = await _cropImage(File(pickedFile.path));
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = croppedFile as File?;
        _imageFiles.add(_imageFile!);
      });
    }
  }

  Future<CroppedFile?> _cropImage(File? imageFile) async {
    if (imageFile == null) {
      return null;
    }
    final croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
      sourcePath: imageFile.path,
      aspectRatio: const CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
      compressQuality: 100,
      maxWidth: 700,
      maxHeight: 700,
      compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
      uiSettings: [
        IOSUiSettings(
          title: 'Crop Image',
          cancelButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
          doneButtonTitle: 'Done',
        ),
        AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarTitle: 'Crop Image',
          toolbarColor: ThemeColors.primary2,
          toolbarWidgetColor: ThemeColors.primary,
          activeControlsWidgetColor: ThemeColors.primary2,
        ),
      ],
    );
    return croppedFile;
  }

  Future<void> _deleteImage(int index) async {
    setState(() {
      _imageFiles.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  Widget _buildImageList() {
    if (_imageFiles.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 150,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: ThemeColors.primary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/picture.png',
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: ThemeColors.lightGray,
            ),
            Text(
              'No images selected\nRecommended (720px X 720px)',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: ThemeColors.lightGray,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 13,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: _imageFiles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final file = _imageFiles[index];
          return Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                height: 200.0,
                child: Card(
                  child: Image.file(
                    file,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                  onPressed: () => _deleteImage(index),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }```
I add the images using a button and display the list in the body of a scaffold in this container:
```Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: ThemeColors.primary,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                      child: _buildImageList(),
                    ),
                  ),```
Its not showing any errors but the image list is not displaying. PLEASE HELP...
````

Comment: You need to debug where the problem is. You could if the images are being loaded from the gallery or if the crop image is returning images correctly or if the widget that displays images is getting the images etc. and share your findings.